# How to run py script via crontab on Ubuntu?

Tags: python

here I have python script for png files optimization via optipng.

I want to add crontab job to run every hour to check new files in wp-content directory which were added the last hour.

If I am running script via bash itself, its optimizing all files.
If I change optimize_all to cron_job - nothing happen, despite I just uploaded new PNG files.

Sorry, I am not familiar with Python and would like to know how to fix cron_job function (if its not correct for my purpose) or how to correctly schedule this function to run

```
import os
import time
import glob
from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from os.path import join, getsize

path = '/var/www/html/wp-content'
DELETE_OLD_DAYS = 3


def get_old_dates(days=0):
    for day in range(0, days):
        yield datetime.now() - timedelta(days=day)


def cron_job():
    for dat in get_old_dates(DELETE_OLD_DAYS):
        dir_name = '%s/%s' % (path, dat.strftime('%Y/%m'))
        try:
            for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
                info = os.stat('%s/%s' % (dir_name, filename))
                # get modified time.
                tim = time.localtime(info.st_mtime)
                if tim.tm_year == dat.year and tim.tm_mon == dat.month and tim.tm_mday == dat.day:
                    print tim.tm_year, dat.year, "  ", tim.tm_mon, dat.month, "  ", tim.tm_mday, dat.day
                    file_path = '%s/%s' % (dir_name, filename)
                    print file_path
                    ext = file_path.split('.')[-1].upper()
                    if ext in ["PNG"]:
                        call(["optipng", "-strip all", "-quiet", "-keep", file_path])
                        call(["chown", "www-data:www-data", file_path])
                        call(["chmod", "664", file_path])

                    old = int((dat - timedelta(days=DELETE_OLD_DAYS + 1)).strftime('%s'))
                    os.utime(file_path, (old, old))
        except OSError as ex:
            # print ex
            pass


def optimize_all():
    for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for fil in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(dp, fil)
            print file_path
            ext = file_path.split('.')[-1].upper()
            if ext in ["PNG"]:
                call(["optipng", "-strip all", "-quiet", "-keep", file_path])
                call(["chown", "www-data:www-data", file_path])
                call(["chmod", "664", file_path])

cron_job()
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you set your cronjob using @Sukumar's answer.

His cron job will run every single second of every single day.

What you need is: 0 * * * * - this translates to every hour of every day of every month, ONLY if its the beginning of that hour

The whole cron job can be set to:

```
0 * * * * python3 /path_to_your_script/your_script.py
```

However, this will cause issues if your script depends on grabbing files from specific directories.

A safer way is:

```
0 * * * * cd/path_to_your_script && python your_script.py
```

That way we are working within the scripts folder, as opposed to executing it on a relative path.

Comment: Big ty for your answer about scheduling task. Could you look on my script code and try to figure out why function cron_tab is doing nothing. It supposed to grab png files with modification date not older than 3 days ago and execute optipng for these files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something which is not what you've done here.

Have all the code that needs to be run inside the main function and have a

`__name__=='__main__'` block by which the code will be executed when you run the script directly.

Have all of this in one python script.

Try to schedule the cron-job whenever you want to. you can check the cron format here - https://crontab.guru/

and do something like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/path_to_your_script.py
```